# FailedPreconditionError when attempting to restore model created in tf.layers API

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement a uNet using the tf.layers API. The task is image segmentation. Below, I will provide (in order): the error message, my network definition, my training code and my validation code.

I have been grappling with this issue for days now and simply cannot figure out how to proceed. If anyone can help me out I'll be extremely thankful!

To get to the heart of the matter, when I restore my model, I am given an error message stating

```
   FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value prediction/Level1Encoding/conv1/conv2d/kernel
     [[Node: prediction/Level1Encoding/conv1/conv2d/kernel/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@prediction/Level1Encoding/conv1/conv2d/kernel"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](prediction/Level1Encoding/conv1/conv2d/kernel)]]

Caused by op 'prediction/Level1Encoding/conv1/conv2d/kernel/read', defined at:
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/ipython/start_kernel.py", line 231, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/ipython/start_kernel.py", line 227, in main
    kernel.start()
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2827, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-42-a9ecd95c66cb>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/Karl/Research/NNStuff/NewTumor/eval.py', wdir='/Users/Karl/Research/NNStuff/NewTumor')
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "/Users/Karl/Research/NNStuff/NewTumor/eval.py", line 58, in <module>
    run_model()
  File "/Users/Karl/Research/NNStuff/NewTumor/eval.py", line 42, in run_model
    v_pred = uNet2D(X, BETA, KERNEL_SIZE, False)
  File "/Users/Karl/Research/NNStuff/NewTumor/definitions.py", line 56, in uNet2D
    conv1=tf.layers.conv2d(x,64,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py", line 551, in conv2d
    return layer.apply(inputs)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 503, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 443, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py", line 137, in build
    dtype=self.dtype)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 383, in add_variable
    trainable=trainable and self.trainable)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1065, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 962, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 367, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape, use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 352, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 725, in _get_single_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 199, in __init__
    expected_shape=expected_shape)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 330, in _init_from_args
    self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1400, in identity
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Identity", input=input, name=name)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/Karl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value prediction/Level1Encoding/conv1/conv2d/kernel
     [[Node: prediction/Level1Encoding/conv1/conv2d/kernel/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@prediction/Level1Encoding/conv1/conv2d/kernel"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](prediction/Level1Encoding/conv1/conv2d/kernel)]]
```

This corresponds to the very first layers of my network.

The network is defined thusly:

```
def uNet2D(x, REGULARIZER, KERNEL_SIZE, IS_TRAINING):
regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=REGULARIZER)

#L1 encode
with tf.variable_scope('Level1Encoding'):
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        conv1=tf.layers.conv2d(x,64,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv1  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv1,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
        conv2=tf.layers.conv2d(conv1,64,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv2  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv2,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2)
    with tf.variable_scope('conv3'):
        conv3=tf.layers.conv2d(conv2,64,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv3  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv3,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv3)

    conv3mp=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv3,2,2,padding='same')

with tf.variable_scope('Level2Encoding'):
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        conv4=tf.layers.conv2d(conv3mp,128,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv4  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv4,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv4)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
        conv5=tf.layers.conv2d(conv4,128,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv5  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv5,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv5 = tf.nn.relu(conv5)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv3'):
        conv6=tf.layers.conv2d(conv5,128,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv6  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv6,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv6 = tf.nn.relu(conv6)

    conv6mp=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv6,2,2,padding='same')

with tf.variable_scope('Level3Encoding'):
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        conv7=tf.layers.conv2d(conv6mp,256,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv7  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv7,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv7 = tf.nn.relu(conv7)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):    
        conv8=tf.layers.conv2d(conv7,256,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv8  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv8,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv8 = tf.nn.relu(conv8)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv3'):
        conv9=tf.layers.conv2d(conv8,256,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv9  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv9,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv9 = tf.nn.relu(conv9)

    conv9mp=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv9,2,2,padding='same')

with tf.variable_scope('Level4Encoding'):
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        conv10=tf.layers.conv2d(conv9mp,512,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv10  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv10,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv10 = tf.nn.relu(conv10)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
        conv11=tf.layers.conv2d(conv10,512,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv11  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv11,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv11 = tf.nn.relu(conv11)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv3'):
        conv12=tf.layers.conv2d(conv11,512,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv12  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv12,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv12 = tf.nn.relu(conv12)

    conv12mp=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv12,2,2,padding='same')


with tf.variable_scope('Level5'):
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        conv13=tf.layers.conv2d(conv12mp,1024,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv13  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv13,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv13 = tf.nn.relu(conv13)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
        conv14=tf.layers.conv2d(conv13,1024,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv14  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv14,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv14 = tf.nn.relu(conv14)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv3'):
        conv15=tf.layers.conv2d(conv14,1024,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv15  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs=conv15,
        axis=-1,
        momentum=0.999,
        epsilon=0.001,
        center=True,
        scale=True,
        training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv15 = tf.nn.relu(conv15)

    conv15=tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv15,512,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, strides=(2,2),padding='same')

with tf.variable_scope('Level4Decoding'):
    inp     = tf.concat([conv12,conv15],3)
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        conv16  = tf.layers.conv2d(inp,256,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv16  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
                inputs=conv16,
                axis=-1,
                momentum=0.999,
                epsilon=0.001,
                center=True,
                scale=True,
                training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv16 = tf.nn.relu(conv16)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
        conv17=tf.layers.conv2d(conv16,256,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv17  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
                inputs=conv17,
                axis=-1,
                momentum=0.999,
                epsilon=0.001,
                center=True,
                scale=True,
                training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv17 = tf.nn.relu(conv17)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv3'):
        conv18=tf.layers.conv2d(conv17,256,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv18  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
                inputs=conv18,
                axis=-1,
                momentum=0.999,
                epsilon=0.001,
                center=True,
                scale=True,
                training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv18 = tf.nn.relu(conv18)

    conv18=tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv18,256,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE),strides=(2,2), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')

with tf.variable_scope('Level3Decoding'):
    inp     = tf.concat([conv9,conv18],3)
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        conv19  = tf.layers.conv2d(inp,128,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv19  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
                inputs=conv19,
                axis=-1,
                momentum=0.999,
                epsilon=0.001,
                center=True,
                scale=True,
                training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv19 = tf.nn.relu(conv19)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
        conv20=tf.layers.conv2d(conv19,128,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv20  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
                inputs=conv20,
                axis=-1,
                momentum=0.999,
                epsilon=0.001,
                center=True,
                scale=True,
                training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv20 = tf.nn.relu(conv20)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv3'):
        conv21=tf.layers.conv2d(conv20,128,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv21  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
                inputs=conv21,
                axis=-1,
                momentum=0.999,
                epsilon=0.001,
                center=True,
                scale=True,
                training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv21 = tf.nn.relu(conv21)

    conv21=tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv21,128,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, strides=(2,2),padding='same')

with tf.variable_scope('Level2Decoding'):
    inp     = tf.concat([conv6,conv21],3)
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        conv22  = tf.layers.conv2d(inp,64,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv22  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
                inputs=conv22,
                axis=-1,
                momentum=0.999,
                epsilon=0.001,
                center=True,
                scale=True,
                training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv22 = tf.nn.relu(conv22)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
        conv23  = tf.layers.conv2d(conv22,128,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv23  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
                inputs=conv23,
                axis=-1,
                momentum=0.999,
                epsilon=0.001,
                center=True,
                scale=True,
                training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv23 = tf.nn.relu(conv23)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv3'):
        conv24=tf.layers.conv2d(conv23,128,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv24  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
                inputs=conv24,
                axis=-1,
                momentum=0.999,
                epsilon=0.001,
                center=True,
                scale=True,
                training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv24 = tf.nn.relu(conv24)

    conv24=tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv24,64,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, strides=(2,2),padding='same')

with tf.variable_scope('Level1Decoding'):
    inp     = tf.concat([conv3,conv24],3)
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        conv25  = tf.layers.conv2d(inp,64,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv25  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
                inputs=conv25,
                axis=-1,
                momentum=0.999,
                epsilon=0.001,
                center=True,
                scale=True,
                training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv25 = tf.nn.relu(conv25)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
        conv26  = tf.layers.conv2d(conv25,128,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv26  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
                inputs=conv25,
                axis=-1,
                momentum=0.999,
                epsilon=0.001,
                center=True,
                scale=True,
                training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv26 = tf.nn.relu(conv26)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv3'):
        conv27  = tf.layers.conv2d(conv26,128,(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
        conv27  = tf.layers.batch_normalization(
                inputs=conv26,
                axis=-1,
                momentum=0.999,
                epsilon=0.001,
                center=True,
                scale=True,
                training = IS_TRAINING)
        conv27=tf.nn.relu(conv27)

    convOUT = tf.layers.conv2d(conv27,1,(1,1),  kernel_regularizer=regularizer, padding='same')
    return convOUT
```

And the code I am using to train it is pretty short and simple:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import os
from scipy.io import loadmat
from random import randint
from definitions import *


tf.reset_default_graph()

#HYPERPARAMS
LR           = 1e-5
EPS          = 1e-12
BETA         = .1
BATCH_SIZE   = 1
NUM_STEPS    = 10 #number of iterations before we save
KERNEL_SIZE  = 3

training=Dataset2D('/Users/Karl/Research/NNStuff/Tumor/Testing/')

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[BATCH_SIZE, 256, 256, 5],   name='X')  #input
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [BATCH_SIZE, 256, 256, 1], name='Y')  #'labels'


def run_model():

GLOBAL_STEP = 0

with tf.variable_scope('prediction') as scope:
    t_pred = uNet2D(X, BETA, KERNEL_SIZE, True)  
    t_cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.reshape(Y,[-1]),logits=tf.reshape(t_pred,[-1])))
    scope.reuse_variables()
    v_pred = uNet2D(X, BETA, KERNEL_SIZE, False)  
    v_cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.reshape(Y,[-1]),logits=tf.reshape(v_pred,[-1])))


optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LR).minimize(t_cost)

with tf.name_scope("training"):
    tf.summary.scalar("training_cost", t_cost, collections=['training'])

with tf.name_scope("validation"):
    tf.summary.scalar("validation_cost", v_cost, collections=['validation'])
    #tf.summary.image("VALIDATION_X",X, collections=['validation'])
    #tf.summary.image("VALIDATION_Y",Y, collections=['validation'])
    #tf.summary.image("VALIDATION_PRED", v_pred, collections=['validation'])


saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    train_merge      = tf.summary.merge_all(key='training')
    validation_merge = tf.summary.merge_all(key='validation')
    print('Beginning Session!')
    writer  =  tf.summary.FileWriter ( './graphs' ,  sess.graph)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('Running Model!')
    while True:
        if GLOBAL_STEP % NUM_STEPS != 0:
            x,y=training.drawBatch(BATCH_SIZE)
            y=np.expand_dims(y,-1)
            _, c, summary = sess.run([optimizer, t_cost, train_merge], feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y})
            print(c)
        else:
            x,y=training.drawBatch(BATCH_SIZE)
            y=np.expand_dims(y,-1)
            c, summary = sess.run([v_cost, validation_merge], feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y})
            save_path=saver.save(sess, './TumorOUT/model')
            print('val')
            print(c)

run_model()
```

I am trying to store and evaluate the model thusly:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu May 24 20:03:35 2018

@author: Karl
"""

from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import os
from scipy.io import loadmat
from random import randint
from definitions import *


tf.reset_default_graph()

#HYPERPARAMS
LR           = 1e-5
EPS          = 1e-12
BETA         = .1
BATCH_SIZE   = 1
NUM_STEPS    = 10 #number of iterations before we save
KERNEL_SIZE  = 3

#training=Dataset2D('/Users/Karl/Research/NNStuff/Tumor/Testing/')

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[BATCH_SIZE, 256, 256, 5],   name='X')  #input
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [BATCH_SIZE, 256, 256, 1], name='Y')  #'labels'


def run_model():

    GLOBAL_STEP = 0

    with tf.variable_scope('prediction') as scope:
        v_pred = uNet2D(X, BETA, KERNEL_SIZE, False)  
        v_cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.reshape(Y,[-1]),logits=tf.reshape(v_pred,[-1])))

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/Users/Karl/Research/NNStuff/NewTumor/TumorOUT/model.meta')
        new_saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/Users/Karl/Research/NNStuff/NewTumor/TumorOUT/'))   
        print('Beginning Session!')
        print('Running Model!')
        while True:
                x,y=training.drawBatch(BATCH_SIZE)
                y=np.expand_dims(y,-1)
                c = sess.run([v_cost], feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y})
                print('val')
                print(c)

run_model()
```

Answer (score 0):

`import_meta_graph` will create new ops corresponding to the saved graph, and the saver it returns will only restore those variables. So you'd either want to use the variables from the MetaGraph (you can get them by name from the current Graph), or just load the checkpoint without loading the MetaGraph if you want to use the variables/ops that are defined in Python.